# Different Chrome checkbox styles

Tags: css, google-chrome, checkbox

I have the same version of Chrome 31 open for two sites, and one site has the checkbox on the right, and I checked the styles in the debugger but I can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

[image]
[image]

it must be a custom Chrome style applied since it's just using standard `<input type="checkbox" />`

this is the checkbox with a larger css `width` and `height`:

[image]

Both sites use `<input type="checkbox">`

Comment: did you check what frameworks, plugins get loaded for each site ? In the debugger see what scripts are loaded for each site .. maybe one of them is changing the checkboxes for one of the sites

Comment: check for this one maybe prettyCheckable ( prettyCheckable.js ) or prettyCheckable.css http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/

Comment: Which website is it? I'm sure it's being done such that the actual input is hidden and you're just seeing a pretty version that looks like an input. That's how it's done on prettyCheckable as well.

Comment: it is an internal site, and actually it's the same site, but the second checkbox is on a slightly older version, so something changed, but I can't seem to figure out what it is. I am hoping it's a simple alternate CSS style or something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out. The other site was zoomed slightly in Chrome. The CSS style to flip to the alternate rendering is...zoom.

`zoom: 1.1`

Comment: Apparently any zoom other than === 1 triggers browser's default rendering.  I'm using .9999 to get Chrome to render correctly.  I tried 1.0001, but it messes up Safari.

Comment: for me the zoom style it was'nt sufficient on windows i must use the transform, like describe in this article https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111406 .

Answer (score 9):

I made a version which doesn't require using `<label>` tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/4bs8A/

1 snippet of css changes all checkboxes with little hassle, was the aim I was going for.

Didn't spend long on the style, but you get the gist.

Comment: Thanks, was theming a mybb site and only saw people saying use <label> which was no use.. So put this together, they're the most impossible things to style, but worth it!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the case that the latest chrome and IE, im contrast to Firefox is able to scale checkboxes and radio buttons to the required width and height.

The following code will scale the radios and checkboxes to 50px x 50px large checkboxes.

```
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    height: 50px; width: 50px;
}
```

Please compare the appearance in different browsers:
https://jsfiddle.net/t9q0mny2/

Answer (score 0):

First checkbox is default, second checkbox is custom. Standart checkbox drawn by each browser in its own way. Custom checkbox changes its appearance with a JS+CSS for IE8 and early or only with CSS with use `:before` and `:after`.
 [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LJW3U/) with clear CSS

Comment: it looks good, but I'm still trying to figure out if the other checkbox is a custom one or if Chrome supports another version using something like -webkit-appearance?